# Why does the text been stretched when I rotate iPhone to landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I wrote the UIView descendant in Xamarin and overrided Draw method.
Among other staff it draws text. It looks good in any screen orientation, but when I rotate device to the other orientation the text is stretched or shrinks. 
[image: original][image: rotated screen]
The drawing code is:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
    var ss = new UIStringAttributes();
    ss.ForegroundColor = mTextColor;
    ss.Font = mTextFont;
    ss.ParagraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle() { Alignment = UITextAlignment.Center };
    using (var g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {
        for (nint i = 0; i < mBars.Length; ++i)
        {
            var r = mBars[i];
            g.SetFillColor(i + 1 == mBars.Length ? mLastBarColor : mBarColor);
            g.FillRect(r);

            var ns = new NSAttributedString(mDataSource[i].Item2, ss);
            var textRect = new CGRect(r.Left, r.Bottom, r.Width, mTextRectHeight);
            ns.DrawString(textRect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not redrawing the image on orientation change - so the existing image is stretched / compressed.  You just need to force a redraw on orientation change

Comment: @Russel, yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russell is right. I didn't know about [UIView contentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode).
It has to be set to 'redraw'